# How do I get passed the "MBR-helper missing" error message in installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I'm entirely new to Linux/Ubuntu so please bear with me.

I currently have Windows 7 32Bit and wanted to install Ubuntu. I used the installation off the website and copied it onto my bootable USB. As I installed Ubuntu it says I need to reboot my system - so I did.

As I try to boot up in Ubuntu it just simply says 'MBR-helper missing' and nothing else, however, it lets me boot back up in Windows fine.

Is there a way to get around or repair this error? I can't find a clear answer on forums.

Is this error because I copied it into my USB? Or is this a common yet fixable problem?

Please help.

Comment: How did you "copy" it to usb, a program like unetbootin or rufus?

Answer (score 0):

Try redownloading the iso. Also don't forget to check the MD5Sum and make sure they are the same

[How to check MD5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Answer (score -1):

If your Master Boot Record broke during the install, Windows may most probably auto-fix that. Type `chkdsk /f /r` to Windows commandline (run as administrator).

Comment: Here's the result I got.. http://gyazo.com/32ff2b5e8d1f17da6236f35859b9ce3d

Comment: well, press y and shutdown your PC. As you open Windows back the command prompt will come up instead, and when it's done,you'll see the Windows logon screen. If it fails, create a Ubuntu Boot Repair disk with your USB as a last resort: [Ubuntu Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)